# Raspberry Pi - Raspbian [ls -l dev/]

Tags: raspbian

I accidentally broke my permissions in `/dev`. Can someone send me default?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I accidentally broke my permissions in /dev

Those are not permanent files stored anywhere, they are kernel interface nodes and created during boot.  Just make sure the directory itself has the correct ownership and permissions:

```
sudo chown root:root /dev
sudo chmod 755 /dev
```

And reboot.